# Is accessing data from a file - with open() and close() Python functions - many times in quick succession not somehow bad for the hardware?

Tags: python, search

I have a search script that:

- opens a file
- finds a given item in a very small list
- closes the file

Is such file juggling for a high number of iterations of this loop, not somehow detrimental to my hardware?

Comment: Not detrimental to your hardware but unnecessary. Just read the entire contents of the file (unless you think it's going to change) into memory and build a list or dictionary as appropriate

Answer (score 0):

The kernel will **cache** files that are read repeatedly, so the disk won’t even be accessed after the first time (unless there is severe memory pressure).  Not that *reading* from an SSD is what wears it out, and if the file were small you wouldn’t necessarily even seek on a spinning disk if there were no other disk activity.